# UICollectionview Reuse Existing cell

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview, ios9, uicollectionviewcell

I want to generate collectionview with 100 number of cells, But it should not to be reallocate at every time of scrolling, But in my code its always creating cells newly.

any one help me to avoid this issue, please find my code below,

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return colorArray.count        
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let colleCell: colorCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colorCell

    colleCell.bgColor.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Red") as! CGFloat/255, green: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Green") as! CGFloat/255, blue: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Blue") as! CGFloat/255, alpha: 1.0)

    return colleCell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let cell:colorCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! colorCell

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    selectedColor = indexPath.row

    sampleColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Red") as! CGFloat/255, green: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Green") as! CGFloat/255, blue: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Blue") as! CGFloat/255, alpha: 1.0)

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Red") as! CGFloat/255, green: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Green") as! CGFloat/255, blue: colorArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Blue") as! CGFloat/255, alpha: 0.7)

    sampleColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 75
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let cell:colorCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! colorCell

    selectedIndex = -1;

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

}
```

Comment: How do you know that it is allocating new cells instead of reusing them?

Comment: By knowing of its cell border color changing while swiping collectionview after selecting cell

Comment: I just want to show to user which cell selected and which is not by changing cell border color, how I can do that?

Comment: In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you need to compare the indexPath.item with the selected item and change the border color as required.

Comment: thanks can you send me back with updated lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's reused correctly, plz double check? But I suggest the way to set selected/deselected cell's style, you can override selected property of  UICollectionViewCell.

```
class ColorCell : UICollectionViewCell{
    override var selected: Bool{
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = selected ? 2 : 0
            layer.borderColor = selected ? UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor : UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        }
    /* your code */
}
```

and UICollectionViewDelegate implementation:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   selectedColor = indexPath.row
   sampleColorView.backgroundColor = /*Color*/
   view.backgroundColor = /*Color*/
   sampleColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 75
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedIndex = -1;
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply,